# Are these the same or different?

Tags: word-choice, comparisons

What's the difference between these two sentences?

> - This movie is hardly as interesting as that one.
> - That movie is almost more interesting than this one.

I would like a native speaker's opinion on this.

Comment: 1234, in my opinion that phrases are completely different from each other, the former implying, differently from the latter, the movie is *less and less* interesting.

Comment: As a native speaker, I've never heard nor used either of these expressions. You'd more commonly say'this movie is not as boring (or interesting) as that one' and, in the second example, 'the other movie was marginally less boring (or interesting) than this one'. But I'm English and in the UK, could be different in the States.

Comment: The sentences are similar in the sense that they are very confusing and quite unlikely to ever be said by a native speaker, especially the second one. They are different in that they mean different things (once you take the time to figure out what they actually mean). The first means that it is _unlikely_ that movie A is as interesting as movie B; the second means that movie A is probably _equally_ interesting as movie B—almost, but not quite, managing to be _more_ interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Neither sentence would be commonly used. Because of the uncommon construction, it's reasonable that there is a reason for using it: it's a rhetorical device.

The first sentence is an example of *litotes,* understatement. The literal meaning is that "this movie" is not as interesting as "that movie": the intended meaning is that it is **far less** interesting.

The second sentence could be taken the same way. There is a literal meaning, that "that movie" is almost, but not quite, as interesting as "this one". The intended *ironic* interpretation is probably that **neither** movie is particularly interesting.